# Travis and matrix combinations

Tags: travis-ci

I want to test different builds of my .js framework against many browsers

I expected to write something like:

```
language: node_js
node_js:
- 0.11
env:
  matrix:
    - BUILD='nocompat'
    - BUILD='compat'
    - BUILD='default'

    - BROWSER='ie6'
    - BROWSER='ie7'
    # etc... about total 15 browsers/platforms
```

But the only way I got it working was specifying all combinations "by hand"...

Like:

```
env:
  matrix:
    - BROWSER='chrome_linux'    BUILD='default'
    - BROWSER='chrome_linux'    BUILD='compat'
    - BROWSER='chrome_linux'    BUILD='nocompat'
    - BROWSER='firefox'         BUILD='default'
    - BROWSER='firefox'         BUILD='compat'
    - BROWSER='firefox'         BUILD='nocompat'

    # etc ... and this is about 50 lines!
```

Is there another way to do this? Or is this the right way?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Looks like you can't DRY right now: [travis-ci issue #1519](https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci/issues/1519)

Comment: Kiitos, Oleg. Would be nice if they fixed it soon though.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the syntax for travis-build matrix environmental variables is:

```
env:
  - STUFF=true
  - STUFF=false
```

The `env: matrix:` is used for specifying variables that stay in the build matrix when you have a `env:global` for variables that aren't used for the build matrix.

You can read up more on matrices [here](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/customizing-the-build/#Build-Matrix). As a note, 50 seperate builds for your project is a little crazy, in fact, I'm not sure travis-ci supports 50 different builds in a matrix. I would narrow it down to about 10-20 personally.

Comment: Tried defining variables in outside the `env: matrix:` as suggested but got  error: `expected <block end>, but found Key while parsing a block collection`

Comment: Joshua, yes. __[And it works](https://travis-ci.org/SergioCrisostomo/mootools-core/builds/20853275)__, but I would like it to be more clean

Comment: Sorry, I meant the yml with env variables set as I suggested.

Comment: Joshua, sorry for late reply. I still didn't find a better way. To answer your question: it doesn't work if the variables are directly under `env:` like you suggested